# Why is adding \usepackage{physics} causing an error with \let\left\relax

Tags: errors

The following small MWE gives an error, TeX Live 2014

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}    
\let\left\relax
\let\right\relax

\begin{document}    
$\frac{a^2 \left(-\log \left(a^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2 y(x)}{b^2 x^2}}
  +1\right)-\frac{2 a^2 y(x)}{b x^2}\right)-\frac{2 a 
  \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2-4 b \sqrt{\frac{a^2 y(x)}{b^2 x^2}}}
  {a \sqrt{a^2+8 b}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}}\right)}{2 b}=
  \frac{a^2 \log (x)}{b}+c_1,y(x)$    
\end{document}
```

When commenting off the `physics` package it compiles OK!

P.S. I am using the `\let\left\relax` etc. code to help format long expression when I noticed that it gives an error only when I include the physics package.

```
pdflatex foo.tex
.......
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.15   \frac{a^2 \log (x)}{b}
                             +c_1,y(x)$
?
```

I have removed the physics package for now. But I am wondering why this happens only with the physics package as I include many other packages without any problem.

Comment: You may say `\let\left\begingroup` and `\let\right\endgroup`; but the problem is in the autogenerated text, of course.

Comment: You could also load `\usepackage[notrig]{physics}`, that avoids the redefinitions involvong `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with the `physics` package as you already mention. And it is only

```
\frac{a^2 \log (x)}{b}+c_1,y(x)
```

that is problematic, that is it is actually `\log`, remove it and the MWE works just fine.

The `physics` package messes with `\log`, even after looking at the code, I do not quite understand why.

---

Update: Physics makes `\log(x)` have autoscaling fences (not a good idea in general, as we've said may times). It does this with something similar to

```
\normallog \argopen( x \argclose)
```

which again is similar to

```
\normallog \mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left( a \aftergroup\egroup\right)
```

A `\left...\right` pair forms a group. So when you let them relax, I'm guessing the `\aftergroup` will be malplaced giving you the error.

In short, don't do that ;-)

Comment: Why `\argclose` isn't defined as `\def\mathclose#1{\right#1\egroup}`? The problem would be disappear. I know that `\aftregroup` trick is used for cases like `\right\delimiter number` but this situation doesn't occur in `\log` argument which is scanned as one-token-left ... one-token-right.

Comment: Don't ask me, I didn't write the `physics` package ;-) Aren't that `\mathclose` needed to get rid of the extra space inserted by a `\left...\right` pair?

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with an up-to-date TL 2014:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{multline}
 \frac{a^2}{2b} \left(-\log \left(a^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2 y(x)}{b^2 x^2}}
  +1\right)-\frac{2 a^2 y(x)}{b x^2}\right)-\frac{2 a 
  \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2-4 b \sqrt{\frac{a^2 y(x)}{b^2 x^2}}}
  {a \sqrt{a^2+8 b}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+8 b}}\right) \\
  = \frac{a^2 \log (x)}{b}+c_1,y(x) 
\end{multline}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update TL and try when I get the chance in short time. (this TL was installed about 2 months ago). But you are not using the same MWE code I posted, with those `\let` commands. Does the same exact code I posted compile ok for you with updated TL?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. `physics` itself needs the original definitions of `\left/\right`.

Comment: This code also runs correctly in a current MikTeX 2.9 on Win 8.1

Answer (score 2):

The physics package implements more intelligence to the macros `\log`, `\sin` etc. These macros scan their math parameter and use `\left` `\right` primitives at begin of the parameter by very specific way. When you redefine these primitives then these macros collapse, of course. If you need to redefine `\left` and `\right` and if you need to use physics package then you can try to add:

```
\def\log{\mathop{\rm log}\nolimits}
etc.
```

The question is why you need to use physic package when its intelligence is destroyed by this redefinition.